# How to debug or trace why orchard localization in a module is not working

Tags: debugging, localization, orchardcms

I have two modules I've created. I added localization for both. One works, the other doesn't. I think I've done things right, but obviously not since one is not working.

How can I debug or trace why the localization is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ask it also on http://orchard.codeplex.com/ might increase your chance of getting an answer.
You can always add extra information here:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/localizing-modules